# How should i collect checkbox info into asp.net

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I have self writen grid and need to collect info about checkboxes for Items after submit button click.

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Repeater id="fields" runat="server">

<HeaderTemplate>
<table>
    <tr><td><h3>Fields Info</h3></td><td><h3>Check</h3></td></tr>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
 <tr><td><asp:Label runat="server" 
                    text=<%# Eval("Field")%> /></td><td><asp:CheckBox runat="server" /></td></tr>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit"/>
```

Pleas help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of *info*? If you want to find all your `CheckBoxes` in the repeater you should give them an `ID` and use `RepeaterItem.FindControl("TheID")`. Or you could loop all items and use `Controls.OfType<CheckBox>`:

```
var allCheckBoxes =  fields.Items.Cast<RepeaterItem>()
    .Select(item => new { 
        Label    = item.Controls.OfType<Label>().First(),
        CheckBox = item.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().First()
    });
```

Now you can loop them:

```
foreach(var x in allCheckBoxes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Label: {0} checked: {1}", x.Label.Text, x.CheckBox.Checked ? "yes" : "no");
}
```

or get only the checked:

```
var checkedOnly = allCheckBoxes.Where(x => x.CheckBox.Checked);
foreach(var x in allCheckBoxes){
    //...
}
```

Comment: In this case info about checkboxes(checked,unchecked) doesn`t change after changes on UI

Comment: @IgorDemyanenko: in _what_ case it doesn't change?

Comment: after changes on UI and subbmit button click

Comment: @IgorDemyanenko: it _does_, so there is something else wrong. Maybe you are databinding the repeater on every postback instead of only once. Use the `!Page.IsPostBack`-check. If that doesn't help you have to show some code.